# Replicating Mail Contact "Bubble" in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, text, email, nsstring

When creating a new message using Mail on the iPhone, and after typing the contact, a blue "bubble" appears around the text.  Is there some way I can replicate this behavior in my own application?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I do this and probably the easiest way is with a custom `UIView`. You can draw inside a clipped rounded path with a blue gradient then draw the text on top of it.

You could also take a look at the Three20 project, which has a similar control. However, it's very complicated if you're just looking for that blue bubble.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tom! It appears as if Three20 will work great for this project (as I was aiming to duplicate the whole selection behavior), but I am running into a bit of trouble. It appears as if TTMessageController will work best for this, however I can't figure out a way to have it display correctly with -pushViewController. When I attempt to use this, the view is too small and the navigation icons don't work. I know there is another class that deals with showing these view controllers, but I prefer to use -pushViewController.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: It might be worth starting a new question for this new problem as I've never looked into actually using any of the Three20 controls or views so I can't help you on this one.

Comment: A follow up - my project, TITokenField, is available on Github and is completely open source :)